# Vue.js and vue-moment: "Failed to resolve filter: moment"

Tags: javascript, momentjs, vue.js

Trying to use [vue-moment](https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment). The simplest possible example from the documentation doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/rjcpz9wt/

```
<span>{{ new Date() | moment "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY" }}</span>
```

Gives:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: moment
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vue-moment` is broken.

You can't use it by just adding it as a `<script>` tag. Currently it only works if you use compile it with webpack or browserify, see this [issue](https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment/issues/11) for updates.

It used to work well on the original version:
https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment/tree/fd6fcb901415c1df4c5abb81870d49b346d3732f

See the original version working here: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardog/vaw33sn2/

Also, on Fiddle dont link to files in https://raw.github.com/ , use this nice
[workaround](http://geekdave.com/2013/06/19/linking-raw-github-files-from-jsfiddle/)

Comment: i think so @Gerardo Grignoli ,, :/ , thanks ^.^ i will try it

Answer (score 4):

/////EDIT/////

apparently you don't need to put moment inside a `Vue.filter(....)` at all.

after you entered `Vue.use(VueMoment)` in `main.js`,
simply put a filter as shown in their documentation anywhere in your app and it just works

//////////////

I encountered the same problem, solved it by not using vue filters

this is my workaround,  my main.js looks like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMoment from 'vue-moment';

Vue.use(VueMoment)
```

and in the component wherever i need to use moment it looks like this:

```js
//IN METHODS:
methods: {
    tellTime(time) {
      console.log(this.$moment(time).format(' mm:ss'))
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- OR IN TEMPLATE -->
      {{$moment(timestamp).fromNow()}}
```

Hope someone else would find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest doing it the way you are, you should create the date variable in the javascript code and just access the variable in your Vue. Here is a fiddle showing what I mean

https://jsfiddle.net/rdffywc7/

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: document.body,
  data: {
    date: moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")
  }
})
```

and then in the doc body

```
<span>{{ date }}</span>
```

Comment: Basically you avoided to load vue-moment... Do you know how to make it properly load the JS ?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out... @Ruby I wouldn't recomend this approach for usages different than showing today's date. Because your data model contains the string representation of the date instead of the date itself.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be too late but still useful for others who are facing this problem right now. As @Gerardo Grignoli said, vue-moment is broken so personally I used

```
import moment from "moment"
Vue.prototype.$moment = moment; 
// later in component 
computed: {
    theDate(){ 
        return this.$moment('2019-10-30T11:10:21.484894Z').format('DD.MM.YYYY'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be too late but still useful for others who are facing this problem right now.

But right still working at the same way:

```
import moment from 'moment';
const covertDateToString = value =>
moment(String(value)).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
export default {
  filters: {
data: covertDateToString,
  },....
}
```

This is the way to do it.

```
 <ul>
     <li v-for="person in people" v-bind:key="person.id">
     {{person.name}}{{person.dob | data}}
   </li>
   </ul>
```