# Vue.js - Vuex without Webpack?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using ASP.Net Web Pages (vb Razor) and have been having trouble getting Webpack setup with it and have been suggested elsewhere on stackoverflow ([How to setup ASP.NET Core + Vue.Js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478855/how-to-setup-asp-net-core-vue-js)) to simply use the vue.js CDN without a build system.

Question is: it would be now great to be able to use Vuex for state management but it seems like all the examples use webpack - are there anyways around this without a build system or alternatives to vuex for creating a datastore and mantaining vue's reactivity?

Thanks, and sorry for the uncommon question - I know most people use webpack!

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with *NOT* using webpack.  Perhaps the problem is with the `export` and `import` parts.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks Harry! I have been using ASP.Net javascript bundler to bundle all the javascript libraries but it seems like the issue was asp.net doesn't keep the order you set (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323409/asp-net-mvc-bundle-config-order). It seemed as if webpack was needed but turned out to be a nuance with ASP.Net. Thank you for the offer to help! Much appreciated! Would you know how to setup a function like in the link but written in VB for ASP.Net Razor Web Pages?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Without a package builder you can use the CDN libraries for vuejs and vuex. It's simply a matter of including the vuex cdn after the vuejs cdn as vuex is designed to detect Vue and auto install itself.

you can see a jsfiddle showcasing it here [example](https://jsfiddle.net/44cgwu4h/)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.1.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div>{{ $store.state.count }}</div>
      <button v-on:click="buttonClick">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Vue(
        {
          'el': '#app',
          'store': new Vuex.Store(
            {
              state: {
                count: 0
              },
              mutations: {
                increment (state) {
                  state.count++
                }
              }
            }
          ),
          'methods': {
            'buttonClick': function() {
              this.$store.commit('increment')
            }
          }
        }
      )
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i want the store to be on a seperate file how to i achieve this?

Comment: @naoru Simply house it in it's on .js file something along the lines of 
```const vuex_store = new Vuex.Store(...)```
then in the main script tag you'd have `'store': vuex_store`